# Trouble with water and electric hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, water-pressure, hot-water

So our cold water has low pressure and we've had water problems for over a year now, not sure if that matters. But I was doing the dishes and the hot water started to get cold but i figured someone else had been using it too so it was fine. About 30 minutes later i tried turning on the hot water and it just gurgled, then nothing. Turned on the cold and it was same as always, but when I turned the faucet for hot water while the cold was on as well the water stopped completely. I checked under the house and could hear water running.

Comment: Not enough information, but water running with all the taps off usually means a leak(underground/hidden?).  Turn off hot water heater, because not nice if it drains out.  Is this city or well water?

Comment: Can you share some additional details? Is any water coming from your hot pipes in any location in your house? Is water running even with all the taps shut off? Have you noticed any leaks, pooling or dampness where pipes should run? Can you post photos of the problem areas and describe this better? Take the [tour] for more information on posting good, answerable questions.

Comment: Theres a leak under house. Looks like it's coming direct from the water heater. We use well water so I turn it off at the pump, but as soon as I turn the pump back on water begins pouring immediately as if it's by passing the water heater all together. Had a similar problem before, but after lowering the pressure and replacing the pressure release valve it was fine, doesn't seem to be the issue this time. Cold water works but turning the hot water knob causes the cold water to stop. Its that way in every room. I don't understand how turning the knob for hot would affect the flow of the cold.

Comment: How high do you have your pressure set to?  Pipes last longer at below 80#, better with 60# or below.  Do you know what type of pipes you have?  Imagine this is a pipe leak, not a tank leak.  Tank should have a cold water inlet with shutoff valve, turn that off and see if leak is still there.